# C# get a list of functions that call a certain function

Tags: c#, reflection

This is kind of a tangent to this question:

[Retrieving the calling method name from within a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615940/retrieving-the-calling-method-name-from-within-a-method)

```
public Main()
{
     PopularMethod();
}

public ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     PopularMethod();
}

public Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     PopularMethod();
}

public void PopularMethod()
{
     //Get calling method name
}
```

Is it possible to use reflection to get a list of functions that call upon the "PopularMethod" function in it's body? 
Ie: [Main, ButtonClick, Button2Click]

Update: [C# reflection and finding all references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490025/c-sharp-reflection-and-finding-all-references)
Was what I was looking for! woot! Thank you all

Comment: Sure - static analysis tools within visual studio and other 3rd party tools can do this.  Nothing built in to the framework, though.

Comment: @D Stanley I imagine that these tools parse the actual code and can locate declarations/usages that way.   I wonder why you would want to do this programatically?

Comment: Solution should be similar to this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5490526/324260).

Answer (score 2):

There is an attribute you can use to let the runtime services get this information for you:

```
public void PopularMethod([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{

}
```

Read more here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply Juan, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. That requires PopularMethod to have been called. I'm more looking to get a programmatic call hierarchy using just C# reflection with out having the call any methods.

Comment: I understand now. Take a look at this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861762/finding-all-references-to-a-method-with-roslyn

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`System.Diagnostics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there is `StackTrace` class in there which might be helpful.

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
for(int i =0; i< st.FrameCount; i++ )
{
    // Note that high up the call stack, there is only
    // one stack frame.
    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(i);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("High up the call stack, Method: {0}",
        sf.GetMethod());

    Console.WriteLine("High up the call stack, Line Number: {0}",
        sf.GetFileLineNumber());
}
```

Comment: You could use this to find all called functions which call PopularFunction.  This would not find references to things that were not called, so not sure if this can provide a list of every reference.