# Finding Webservice and DLL reference in .NET WebSites(NOT WebApps)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, system.reflection

We are  having more than 40 websites (Not Web Apps) developed many years ago. 
We are planning to migrate these websites into Web Apps and also we need to remove old web services and DLL.

First step, we need to find all Web Service and DLL references in these Web Sites. 
It should display list of pages web service/DLL methods being referred,  list of line where they are used, input , output parameters. etc.

I am looking for the following list.

- Component    - Name of Webservice/DLL Component
- Sub-Component    - Methods used    in the Component
- Input Parameters  - List of Input parameters
- Output Parameters - List of Output parameters
- Module  - What is calling the component - Example :   Registration page, User Login, Product Registration
- Which page is being called   - Name of ASPX page  - Example - Login.aspx.

I can use Re-sharper going to each web sites and find the references of each web services/DLL and its methods. But the issue is number of web sites are huge. we  don't want to spend time on doing manual work. Also web sites are not Web Apps. So it is not compiled one.

Got a code which is using reflection to find list of methods used inside the DLLs ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490025/c-sharp-reflection-and-finding-all-references)). My need is just opposite to that .

This is similar to the "Find all references" functionality in Visual Studio with more details.

Do we have any tools to do this task?

Comment: No you don't...

Comment: Yes Gusman. It is not straight forward. There is a workaround for that. I have given my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- We can use .NET Compiler Platform called "Roslyn" -
  https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn
- Roslyn provides open-source C# and Visual Basic compilers with rich
  code analysis APIs. It enables building code analysis tools with the
  same APIs that are used by Visual Studio.
- Of course, it is not straight forward but it would reduce the manual work.
- https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/learn-roslyn-now/ - This was interesting to start with.