# How to get all parameter of static method called in a DLL and save to resource file

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, localization

I have a dll, now I want to get all hard code message to resource file.

I want to make a program that input a dll, ouput a resource file with all hard code message.

Current code:

```
if (WinMessage.MsgYesNo("Monitoring Plant", "Files are being processed. Do you really want to exit?") == DialogResult.No)
 {
         return;
 }

public static DialogResult MsgYesNo(string sTitle, string sContent)
{
      //show message code
}
```

In program, I want read all content like "Monitoring Plant", "Files are being processed. Do you really want to exit?" and save them to resource file.

I tried to find some reflection way but not success.
[C# reflection and finding all references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490025/c-sharp-reflection-and-finding-all-references)

Suggest me some solution, many thanks.